# pthread_cond_wait never unblocking - thread pools

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I'm trying to implement a sort of thread pool whereby I keep threads in a FIFO and process a bunch of images. Unfortunately, for some reason my cond_wait doesn't always wake even though it's been signaled.

```
        // Initialize the thread pool
        for(i=0;i<numThreads;i++)
        {

            pthread_t *tmpthread = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));

            struct Node* newNode;
            newNode=(struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            newNode->Thread = tmpthread;
            newNode->Id = i;
            newNode->threadParams = 0;
            pthread_cond_init(&(newNode->cond),NULL);
            pthread_mutex_init(&(newNode->mutx),NULL);

            pthread_create( tmpthread, NULL, someprocess, (void*) newNode);
            push_back(newNode, &threadPool);

        }



    for() //stuff here
    {
    //...stuff
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);        
            struct Node *tmpNode = pop_front(&threadPool);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);  

        if(tmpNode != 0)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&(tmpNode->mutx));
                pthread_cond_signal(&(tmpNode->cond)); // Not starting mutex sometimes? 
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tmpNode->mutx));     
        }
    //...stuff
    }

 destroy_threads=1;
 //loop through and signal all the threads again so they can exit. 
 //pthread_join here


}

    void *someprocess(void* threadarg)
    {
        do
        {
    //...stuff
            pthread_mutex_lock(&(threadNode->mutx));
                pthread_cond_wait(&(threadNode->cond), &(threadNode->mutx));
                // Doesn't always seem to resume here after signalled.
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(threadNode->mutx));
        } while(!destroy_threads);

        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

Am I missing something? It works about half of the time, so I would assume that I have a race somewhere, but the only thing I can think of is that I'm screwing up the mutexes? I read something about not signalling before locking or something, but I don't really understand what's going on.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your example shows you locking the `queueMutex` around the call to `pop_front`, but not round `push_back`. Typically you would need to lock round both, unless you can guarantee that all the pushes happen-before all the pops.

Secondly, your call to `pthread_cond_wait` doesn't seem to have an associated predicate. Typical usage of condition variables is:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
while(!ready)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mtx);
}
do_stuff();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
```

In this example, `ready` is some variable that is set by another thread whilst that thread holds a lock on `mtx`.

If the waiting thread is not blocked in the `pthread_cond_wait` when `pthread_cond_signal` is called then the signal will be ignored. The associated `ready` variable allows you to handle this scenario, and also allows you to handle so-called *spurious wake-ups* where the call to `pthread_cond_wait` returns without a corresponding call to `pthread_cond_signal` from another thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'pthread_cond_wait' is confusingly named. It is not a conditional wait, it is an UNconditional wait *for* a condition. You must not call it if you do not need to wait.

Comment: Yes; that is yet another reason why you need the `ready` variable, or other associated predicate.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but I think you don't have to (you must not) lock the mutex in the thread pool before calling  pthread_cond_signal(&(tmpNode->cond)); , otherwise, the thread which is woken up won't be able to lock the mutex as part of pthread_cond_wait(&(threadNode->cond), &(threadNode->mutx)); operation.

Comment: Thanks, but it still causes the same problem unfortunately :(

Comment: Sure it will. It will lock the mutex as soon as the mutex is released. You can hold the mutex as long as you need it so long as you release is eventually.