# pthreads: different behaviour on different thread count

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

So, I have a code (thread pool like) that creates few pthreads.
They are blocked on mutex first (while all threads not created) then wait on conditional variable until main thread broadcasts them a notification.

I test this code on two PC: **1st** - gentoo x64 with 2 core AMD, **2nd** - mandriva x32 with p4 (HT on). And I got different results.

It works well on **1st** PC with 2 threads in pool, and on **2nd** with 3 threads in pool.
But!
**1st** PC with thread count more then 2: throws error EPERM from main thread while unlocking mutex (locked before).
**2nd** PC with thread count more then 3: throws error EINVAL from main thread while unlocking mutex (locked before) and from all sequential calls to mutex and cond from created threads.

Any Idea? :)

*p.s. threads mutex and cond created with NULL attrs*

main():

```
...
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&queue_condition, NULL);
running = true;

lock();
while(pool_size<limit) {
    pthread_create(&threads[pool_size++], NULL, &run, this)    
}
unlock();

sleep(2);
schedule(new SimpleJob(...));
sleep(2);
...
```

run():

```
while (running) {
    lock();
    Job* job = next();

    if (job == NULL) {
        wait();
        unlock();
        continue;
    }
    unlock();
    job->execute();
    delete job;
}
```

routine:

```
void lock() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
}
void unlock() {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
void wait() {
    pthread_cond_wait(&queue_condition, &mutex);
}
void notifyAll() {
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&queue_condition);
}
void schedule(Job* job) {
    lock();
    job_queue.push(job);
    notifyAll();
    unlock();
}
Job* next() {
    if (job_queue.empty()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Job* job = job_queue.front();
    job_queue.pop();
    return job;
}
```

output on 2nd PC with 4 threads:

```
3076544208] hi! Im main thread!
3076544208] starting all threads
3076544208] locking...
3076544208] locked
3076544208] init:
3076544208] thread[1] = 3076541296 created
3076544208] thread[2] = 3068148592 created
3076544208] thread[3] = 3059755888 created
3076544208] thread[4] = 3051363184 created
3076544208] init done.
3076544208] unlocking...
3076544208] unlocked error=22
3051363184] run
3051363184] locking...
3051363184] locked error=22
```

Comment: Smells like memory corruption.  Run with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: you mean 2nd PC?  thanks for the link :)

Comment: You have a logic error, a race condition or some memory corruption - or a compbination of the 3 somewhere.

Comment: @ydroneaud code appended to the topic

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989801/pthread-cond-wait-never-unblocking-thread-pools/4991746

Comment: @ydroneaud thanks, but could you please point to mistake in my code. next() function called from lock/unlock block. Note that it works like clockwork with 2/3 threads in pool :)

Comment: Are there only one of mutex, queue_condition and job_queue, or is any of these per thread, per something else ?

Comment: @nos each of them have only one instance

Comment: This obviously isn't your exact code, since it doesn't contain the debugging output statements.  The code you've shown looks OK (though there's no need to hold the lock in the main thread while creating the worker threads, as long as the job queue is already initialised), so you might need to post a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @caf YES, you extremely right! my real code wrapped by a class and uses printf. And the terrible thing that this code (+printf) is really working (I checked it minute ago) but my class isn't :(  I'll try to find the reason personally and will publish results here. Or I can post my real code if anyone is interested in.

Comment: @iheaven  Better to post the real code, minimal real example that doesn't work. It's not clear how your system works from the current code - you mention you have a class somewhere - the error could be a simple as copying a mutex around, an array overflow or something else

Comment: @nos I caught the bug! I forgot to initialize array <code>threads</code> that is a field of my class. @ephemient was right it's memory corruption. Thanks for all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I caught the bug! I forgot to initialize array **`threads`** that is a field of my class. *ephemient* was right it's memory corruption.

Comment: +1 for finding the answer. you can accept your own answer in so.